Electromagnet with ESP32 and MOSFET
I got this circuit that should drive electromagnet from ESP32 using 1RLZ44N MOSFET. I do think I got it correct but would appreciate feedback. I am a little bit uncertain on the placement of the 10 kΩ pull down resistor.
Here is my circuit:


Please DO NOT update your question to correct errors I have already pointed out in my answer.


Your 1N4007 diode is connected the wrong way round
The 10 kΩ resistor is connected correctly
Make sure you don't get ground loops via and ESP32 circuitry
You should be OK with driving the IRLZ44N at 3.3 volt levels but, it really depends on your load current (less than 3 amps is my recommendation)


ok. so now i updated my circuit. correct?
You should be OK with driving the IRLZ44N at 3.3 volt levels but, it really depends on your load current (less than 3 amps is my recommendation)
I might go above that for driving the electromagnet. Actually Im thinking of switching mosfet to for example IRLB8721 which has lower gate threshold voltage. Opinion?

Please provide a link to the MOSFET data sheet.

here you go: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLB8721-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566056732591

I would say it is no better than 3 amps. You have to look at and understand figure 1 in the data sheet. It tells you that with a 3 to 3.5 volt gate drive nearly 1 watt will be dissipated for a 3 amp load. This is just a typical graph and some devices will be worse @acroscene

@acroscene if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
